# Cakephp 3.5 : How to test login functionality without using Fixture for unit testing in phpunit?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.x, phpunit, cakephp-3.5

I am using Cakephp-3.5 Auth Component in my application to verify user's credential. Now I have to write down unit test cases for login form. I have to write test cases not using Fixtures but only just in phpunit. I am unable to figure out how to solve this ?

Comment: Why can't you use fixtures? They're pretty fundamental to unit testing.

Comment: If you want to make your life harder than needed by not using fixtures, you can always mock whatever you need to mock: https://phpunit.de/manual/6.5/en/test-doubles.html

Comment: @GregSchmidt I have tried with Fixtures and it is working fine. So I have started learning more of it. And thanks burzum for response. That also helped.